# What does this encoded message mean? "kzsaain zhps V !vW"

Tags: cipher

The following message was encoded using a simple algorithm:

> `!kzsaain zhps V !vW`

Please try to explain how it works.

Comment: Seems more like (very simple) [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message reads "Hi! I love puzzles!".

It was encrypted using a ROT variant and written backwards.

The ROT variant starts with e mapped to z then as it descends through the alphabet the encrypted characters ascend. When it reaches p, it skips one letter, presumably to avoid being invertible. Then once it runs out of letters at the end z is mapped to a.

```
e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
z y x w v u t s r q p n m l k j i h g f e a
```

The first 4 letters of the alphabet appear to be excluded.

Comment: Good job! And actually the first 4 letters are replaced with code.

Comment: It was the first 4 letters as far as I know were c o d e instead of a b c d

Comment: The ROT variant you have isn't quite right - 'z' should map to 'e', but in the message they have become 'a's.

Comment: @RobWatts You're right, of course - I worked out the skipped letter as I working it out but forgot it by the time I was writing out an answer.